# How to setup nameservers at Freenom

Tags: nameserver

I've been trying to set up a DNS at Freenom for my home server, but every time I change the nameservers it says:

> Invalid nameserver given

The nameservers in my Ubuntu server (`/etc/resolv.conf`) are:

- 212.115.192.193
- 212.115.192.100
- 62.238.255.69

Am I using wrong nameservers? Am I supposed to enter Freenom's nameservers in `resolv.conf`? What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Have you çontacted Freenon?

Comment: yes, i have, but they don't respond. I've tried all the Emails i could find on their site, but with no luck.

Comment: Freenom runs DNS servers that you can use for to point your domain name to your website IP address.   They also run public DNS servers that you can use on your home computer.   It isn't clear which of those you are trying to do based on your question.    See [How to connect a Freenom domain name to my Amazon ec2 instance?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101307/how-to-connect-a-freenom-domain-name-to-my-amazon-ec2-instance)